# Programmatically Creating Combinations- Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created new product with prestashop core classes with an import script. Now I have to generate programmatically the combinations of these products with a standard set of attributes.
What prestashop core functions can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also made a import script and i made these two loop in one of my method

```
    $iDefaultLangId = Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        foreach($aAttributeValues as $sValue) {

            if(!Attribute::isAttribute($iAttributeId, $sValue, $iDefaultLangId)) {
                $oAttribute = new Attribute();
                $oAttribute->id_attribute_group = $iAttributeId;
                $oAttribute->name = array();

                $oAttribute->name[3] = $sValue; //this is the is of your lang

                $oAttribute->add();

                echo "create attribute <br>";

            }
        }

        foreach(AttributeGroup::getAttributes($iDefaultLangId, $iAttributeId) as $aAttribute) {
            if(in_array($aAttribute['name'], $aAttributeValues)) {



                if(!$oProduct->productAttributeExists(array($aAttribute['id_attribute']))) {

                    echo "add combination with quantity " . $combQty ." e valore " . $aAttributeValues[0] . " <br>";

                    if ( $ref != false){

                        $id_product_attribute = $oProduct->addCombinationEntity($oProduct->price, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, array(), $ref, 0, $combEan, false);

                    } else {

                        $id_product_attribute = $oProduct->addCombinationEntity($oProduct->price, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, array(), $aAttribute['name'], 0, $combEan, false);

                    }



                    $combination = new Combination((int)$id_product_attribute);

                    $combination->setAttributes(array($aAttribute['id_attribute']));

                    $this->_setQuantity($oProduct->id, $combination->id, $combQty );

                } else {


                }
```